# masm Irvine32 library. How to print out a single byte

Tags: masm, irvine32

This question asks me to take in a dword and convert it from little endian to big endian. I have got that part down but now I need to print it out.

The call to WriteHex will only print out an entire register. I have also tried to use some math to fit the contents of my array in one register but we are restricted to using mov, add and sub with no loops. Is there a way to print out a single byte using Irvine or mov an array to a register with only those commands?

This is what I have

```
data
    bigEndian BYTE 4 DUP(?)
    littleEndian DWORD ?
    prompt BYTE "Please enter a number in HEX > ",0

.code 
main PROC
    mov edx, offset prompt
    CALL WriteString 
    CALL ReadHex
    mov littleEndian, eax
    mov al, bigEndian + 4
    mov bigEndian, al
    mov al, bigEndian + 5
    mov bigEndian + 1, al
    mov al, bigEndian + 6
    mov bigEndian + 2, al 
    mov al, bigEndian + 7
    mov bigEndian + 3, al
    ; should print here
```

Comment: If you actually want to print the individual bytes, use `movzx eax, BYTE PTR someAddress` to zero-extend a byte from memory into a 32-bit register. Otherwise, see rkhb's answer. Note that everything after `call ReadHex` in your code could be replaced with `bswap eax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-ptr) is the MASM operator to declare or override a type. If you want tp löad a single byte from a DWORD variable you use `BYTE PTR`. If you want to load a DWORD from a BYTE array you use `DWORD PTR`:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    bigEndian BYTE 4 DUP(?)
    littleEndian DWORD ?
    prompt BYTE "Please enter a number in HEX > ",0

.code
main PROC
    mov edx, offset prompt
    CALL WriteString
    CALL ReadHex
    mov littleEndian, eax
    mov al, BYTE PTR littleEndian + 3
    mov bigEndian + 0, al
    mov al, BYTE PTR littleEndian + 2
    mov bigEndian + 1, al
    mov al, BYTE PTR littleEndian + 1
    mov bigEndian + 2, al
    mov al, BYTE PTR littleEndian + 0
    mov bigEndian + 3, al

    mov eax, DWORD PTR bigEndian
    call WriteHex

    exit

main ENDP

END main
```